# How to show disconnect network drives

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-server-2008, network-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make network drives appear even if disconnected?](https://superuser.com/questions/432286/how-to-make-network-drives-appear-even-if-disconnected)

Windows 7 and Vista laptops in my company domain has network drives set up by Win2k8 Server GPO. Normally, when the laptops has ethernet cable plugged in before boot, the network drives connect and appear as expected at the end of startup sequence.

However, when the laptop has ethernet cable unplugged, the network drives are not connected, which is fine, but the disconnected icons disappear as well. i.e. the drives are not set up.

At the end of the startup sequence, upon reaching desktop, the wireless adapters will connect to the network and the laptop will be able to find the network drive. Hence I want the drives to be setup nonetheless, so that the next attempt to connect, say, via a desktop shortcut, will reestablish the network drive connection. How can this be done?

[image: This is what I want: Network drives setup with disconnected icons]

Comment: Exactly which Group Policies do you use to create the network maps? When you unplug the Ethernet cable, how long does it take until the mapped drives vanish?

Comment: It seems you've already asked about this. If you want to get more attention for a question you can always edit it or place a bounty on it.

Comment: @slhck didn't realise I asked it before already. Added a bounty on the previous question as told. Thanks, please delete this question if approperiate.